# Rust way of the generic quicksort implementation

Tags: rust

I have implemented the classical Hoare's algorithm, but I think that the implementation is not readable enough. I have tried to refactor it in the way that I used to use in C#. But now I have got compiler errors.

Let me show some details. This is the first implementation:

```rust
pub fn quicksort<T>(array: &mut Vec<T>) where T: Ord {
    partition(array, 0, array.len() as isize - 1);
}

fn partition<T>(array: &mut Vec<T>, start: isize, end: isize) where T: Ord {
    let length = end - start + 1;
    if length == 0 || length == 1 {
        return;
    }

    let mut left = start;
    let mut right = end;

    loop {
        let pivot = &array[start as usize];
        while array[left as usize] < *pivot {
            left += 1
        }

        while array[right as usize] > *pivot {
            right -= 1
        }

        if left < right {
            array.swap(left as usize, right as usize);
            left += 1;
            right -= 1;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    partition(array, start, right);
    partition(array, right + 1, end);
}
```

It seems it works, at least my tests are passed.

```rust
fn main() {
    test_arrays(&mut vec![], &vec![]);
    test_arrays(&mut vec![1], &vec![1]);
    test_arrays(&mut vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5], &vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    test_arrays(&mut vec![5, 4, 3, 2, 1], &vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    test_arrays(&mut vec![2, 3, 1, 5, 4], &vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
}

fn test_arrays(source: &mut Vec<i32>, target: &Vec<i32>) {
    quicksort(source);

    assert!(source.iter().eq(target.iter()));
}
```

Next are my questions. First, I would rather declare `pivot` as the variable, not the reference:

```rust
loop {
    let pivot = array[start as usize];
    while array[left as usize] < pivot {
        left += 1
    }

    while array[right as usize] > pivot {
        right -= 1
    }
. . .
```

But when I do it, I get the error:

```
   |
29 |         let pivot = array[start as usize];
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                     |
   |                     move occurs because value has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                     help: consider borrowing here: `&array[start as usize]`
```

I get what it means, but I don't want to limit the `question` with the `Copy` trait.

Next, I would rather move `pivot`'s assignment out of the loop:

```rust
let pivot = &array[start as usize];

loop {
    while array[left as usize] < *pivot {
        left += 1
    }

    while array[right as usize] > *pivot {
        right -= 1
    }
. . .
```

When I do it, I get the another error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*array` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src\main.rs:39:13
   |
27 |     let pivot = &array[start as usize];
   |                  ----- immutable borrow occurs here
...
30 |         while array[left as usize] < *pivot {
   |                                      ------ immutable borrow later used here
...
39 |             array.swap(left as usize, right as usize);
   |             ^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

As I get, the compiler has protected me from the case when the `pivot` has changed after the swapping. But I don't like that the `pivot` is recalculated in every iteration of the loop although it keeps the same value in most cases.

I may keep the code with recalculation, or I may add the `Copy` trait.

Finally, I think that the `partition` function is too large. I want to extract the body of loop to the an another function. I can do it if I will add the `Copy` trait to the `quicksort` and `partition` implementations:

```rust
pub fn quicksort<T>(array: &mut Vec<T>) where T: Ord+Copy {
    partition(array, 0, array.len() as isize - 1);
}

fn partition<T>(array: &mut Vec<T>, start: isize, end: isize)
where T: Ord+Copy {
    let length = end - start + 1;
    if length == 0 || length == 1 {
        return;
    }

    let mut left = start;
    let mut right = end;

    loop {
        swap_next_unordered_elements(array, &mut left, &mut right, array[start as usize]);
        if left >= right {
            break;
        }
    }

    partition(array, start, right);
    partition(array, right + 1, end);
}

fn swap_next_unordered_elements<T>(array: &mut Vec<T>, left: &mut isize, right: &mut isize, pivot: T)
where T: Ord+Copy {
    while array[*left as usize] < pivot {
        *left += 1
    }

    while array[*right as usize] > pivot {
        *right -= 1
    }

    if *left < *right {
        array.swap(*left as usize, *right as usize);
        *left += 1;
        *right -= 1;
    }
}
```

As for me, this code looks simpler. Unfortunately, the `quicksort` has had the `Copy` trait that was not needed in the "complicated" version of the code.

So, what is the best solution? Should I keep the first ("complicated") version of the code without `Copy`? Or should I make simpler implementation with the `Copy`?

Or maybe there is another way to make simple generic quicksort?

Comment: Not sure if anyone but me is still paying attention to this 2 year old post, but I'm curious why you're storing the indices as isizes just to convert them to usizes when they're used for indexing into the vec. Also note that you can make these take &[T] instead of &Vec<T>, and still use it the same way at the call site, since &Vec<T> derefs to &[T]. That adds the flexibility that the caller can also pass a &Box<[T]> or a &[T; N].

Comment: @embradley, the `end` variable can have value -1, so it's `isize`. The `start` variable is `isize` for symmetry. Thank you for notice about `&[T]` and `&Vec<T>`. It's because I didn't know Rust good enough that time.

Comment: Am I right that the only way end can be -1 is if the given list is empty from the start? In that case, you could add if list.is_empty() { return } right before the first call to partition, and you’d then know that the arguments for partition are all non-negative.

Comment: @embradley, Hi. That's the place:
`if *left < *right { array.swap(*left as usize, *right as usize); *left += 1;  *right -= 1; // *right can become -1 here }`
```

Comment: @embradley, current version of the code is placed [here](https://github.com/progmsk/tests/blob/main/lesson2/rust/src/lib.rs).

Comment: Got it, thanks for clarifying. One nitpick on the current version: if I were calling `try_swap()` from somewhere else, I would expect it to return a `Result`, not a `bool`. Functions called `try_…()` usually return an error if they fail, not false.

Comment: @embradley, thank you. I have used `bool` because my C# background. :) I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start using references and arrays in rust you tend to run into difficulties with the borrow checker. The borrow checker isn't smart enough to understand the invariants of the algorithm, and thus has to be overly cautious.

There are three solutions:

### Use Indexes

In this approach, you simply never take a reference, always pass around an index. So instead of:

```
let pivot = array[start as usize];
while array[left as usize] < pivot {
    left += 1
}

while array[right as usize] > pivot {
    right -= 1
}
```

You would do:

```
let pivot = start as usize;
while array[left as usize] < array[pivot] {
    left += 1
}

while array[right as usize] > array[pivot] {
    right -= 1
}
```

If you follow this approach consistently, you'll find that borrow checker is happy. However, it does mean re-evaluating `array[pivot]` and similar a lot. After optimizations are applied, this isn't as big a deal as you might think.

### Split Slices

Slices, and by extension `Vec`, have methods that you split it into distinct  slices.

For example, you can do

```
 let (pivot, rest) = array.split_first_mut().unwrap();
```

Now you have independent references to the partition and the rest of the array. The borrow will understand that mutations to rest can't affect the pivot.

This is also a `split_at_mut` that splits at particular index you can use to divide a slice into two slices, perhaps to sort each independently.

### Use Unsafe

You can use the unsafe function `as_mut_ptr` to get a pointer to the vec contents, and then use pointer logic to implement the algorithm with the borrow checker watching over your shoulder. Generally, its not worth doing this, but for some low level code it can make sense. You can also use `get_unchecked` to access the elements of the array without an index.

If you look at the code used in the standard libraries implementation of quicksort, it uses some combination of all three.